# JFrog Pipelines does not come up after an upgrade

Tags: jfrog-pipelines

In the logs, I see the following error:

> 2022-11-15T02:00:52.941Z [jfrou] [FATAL] [1914f17694f779cc] [bootstrap.go:99               ] [main                ] [] - Cluster join: Failed resolving join key: Corrupted join key: encoding/hex: invalid byte: U+006E 'n'

I have uninstalled and installed but still facing the same problem

Answer (score 2):

Check that the correct join key `JF_SHARED_SECURITY_JOINKEY` is added in /opt/jfrog/pipelines/var/etc/router/router_compose.yml and run pipelines restart